# EmbeddedId, sequence and ConstraintViolationException

Tags: hibernate, exception, sequence

I've got entity, which has @EmbeddedId. In the id class there are a few fields, and one of them is Long id with Generation type sequence. Problem apperas when I'm trying to insert instance of this entity, without setting id in embeeded id (which should be inserted here from sequence).

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

When id in this embeddedId is set to any value then insert is successfull.

What can I do to make it work?

Edit: code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TestIds")
public class TestIds implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private TestId testId;

    public TestIds(TestId testId) {
        this.setTestId(testId);
    }

    public TestId getTestId() {
    return testId;
    }

    public void setTestId(TestId testId) {
    this.testId = testId;
    }   
}

@Embeddable
public class TestId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_entity_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName="MY_ENTITY_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "column_name")
    private Long id;

    public TestId() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I'm executing

```
TestIds a = new TestIds(new TestId());
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

session.save(a);
session.flush();

org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

Caused by: 
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into TestIds (column_name) values (NULL) was aborted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is impossible to use @GeneratedValue in @EmbeddedId

Answer (score 0):

you should add the annotation  @GeneratedValue to the id, and take the behavior of your choice .

for example edited for mistake of @Id

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_entity_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName="MY_ENTITY_SEQ")
@Column(name = "column_name")
private Long id;
```

Comment: I've defined sequance generator. Embeddable class cannot have Id.